# postgres locking problem with pgadmin3 and libreoffice

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice, pgadmin

I have a postgresql database accessed from pgadmin3 and libreoffice.
When it is accessed from multiple clients, it seems like only one client can actively access the database. Like there was an exclusive lock. Other clients do freeze.
The database is accessed using ssl authentication.

Comment: What version of postgresql? it's straightforward to confirm an exclusive lock is causing the problem, but the names of the columns in the `pg_stat_activity` query depends on the PG version

Comment: It must be Libreoffice or its driver that locks the tables, because pgAdmin sure doesn't.